# Ender 3 pro Z axis homing

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling

Whenever the printer homes, the nozzle ends up digging into the bed and causing damage. This also happens when I start prints, the first layer is shoving the nozzle into the bed, this happens every time.

This only happens when the bed is level. It only stops when I lower the bed completely. And when I do it is too far down and the nozzle is about a centimetre away from the bed.

I haven't thought much about it until now as I am thinking of replacing the bed because of the damage.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the Z-axis sensor has moved? Has this been happening all the time, i.e. since you bought it, or did this just recently happen? If so, did you change anything?

Comment: When my ender homes Z, it has moved the platform out of the way so the nozzle can go below the platform without touching it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have incorrectly set up your machine, specifically the Z offset.
Or your Z endstop is physically too low and not set up properly.

I'd suggest recalibrating your machine from the start as that would help dial it in as well as potentially solve this issue.

I recommend following this guide at the [Teaching Tech 3D Printer Site](http://teachingtechyt.github.io/) - it's extremely good. (there's also a page for troubleshooting different issues including testing your Endstops to confirm they are working)

Good Luck. 3D printers can be hella finickity but all in good fun.